# Combinations of elements 2D array C

Tags: arrays, c

I have such piece of code:

```
    for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++) {
            case '2':
                strcpy(letters[i], "abc");
                break;
            case '3':
                strcpy(letters[i], "def");
                break;
            case '4':
                strcpy(letters[i], "def");
                break;
            case '5':
                strcpy(letters[i], "jkl");
                break;
            case '6':
                strcpy(letters[i], "mno");
                break;
            case '7':
                strcpy(letters[i], "pqrs");
                break;
            case '8':
                strcpy(letters[i], "tuv");
                break;
            case '9':
                strcpy(letters[i], "wxyz");
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have to get different combinations of chars from different elements. For example, if user prints 575, this piece of code will make 2D array {"jkl", "pqrs", "jkl"}. And after that I should also make 2D array with different combinations of letters, one letter from element (for example {"jpj", "jpk", "jpl", "krl"} etc). And the problem is with making these combinations. I don't understand how can I do that. It's also forbidden to work with dynamic memory (malloc, free, etc) and ready functions for sorting (qsort, lsearch, etc).

I tried to use nested loops and recursive but I don't know how to use it in this situation correctly. I'd be extremely grateful for any help, both theoretical or practical.

Comment: "It's also forbidden to..." - that's a dumb exercise. You can roll your own (albeit limited) dynamic memory with a large enough array on the stack, and you can find sorting functions online ready to be copy-pasted. What is this for exactly?

Comment: how is the `letters array defined??

Comment: @Nelfeal I agree with you that is extremely dumb. That's a university homework so I have to fulfill the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Letter sets**

The solution below uses only iteration. Getting the 2D array of the letter sets is fairly simple and uses the code you already have. An important detail to note is that if you what those letter sets to be printable, you need to account for the extra null termination character `'\0'`. Therefore, each row of the letter set array will contain the maximum number of letters + 1, i.e. 4+1 characters.

**Combinations array**

To generate the combinations without dynamic array resizing, you will need to know how many combinations exists. This is calculated as the product of the number of letters of each set. So now, you can declare a static array with 1 row per combination and `n+1` columns, one for each letter set plus the null-terminating character.

**Representing a combination**

Apart from the obvious letter-based way, a combination can be represented as a vector of indices, where the i-th index denotes the selected character from the i-th character set. Thus, the vector `(0, 0, 2)` represents the combination where the first character is taken from the first set, the first character is taken from the second set and the third character is taken from the third set.

With this index vector, it is easy to construct the respective string. The advantage is that it is also easy to generate the next combination as well! Starting from the last index, increment it if the resultant index is less than the size of the letter set. If so, then you have a new index vector representing a new *unseen* combination. If the resultant index exceeds the set size, then you need to set it to zero and apply this process to the next (towards the left) index of the vector until a valid increment is found.

**Combinations order**

You want all the combinations to be sorted. Notice that the letters in all sets are sorted. Thus the combinations themselves, following the procedure I described, will also be sorted, because you are exhaustively generating them from the last character to the first **and** the characters in each place are provided in lexicographic order. So there is no need to explicitly sort the result.

*Note:* in the code, for easy testing, I use a local variable `arg` to provide the input digits. Simply change that to take the input from `argv[1]`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    
    char *arg = "575";
    
    // Get length of argument (denotes number of letter sets)
    int n = strlen(arg);
    if (n == 0){
        printf("No digits given");
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Declare 2D array of letters (n rows, 5 columns)
    char letters[n][5];
    
    int total_combinations = 1;
    
    // Fill array with characters
    for (int i = 0; arg[i]; i++) {
        switch(arg[i]){
            case '2':
                strcpy(letters[i], "abc");
                break;
            case '3':
                strcpy(letters[i], "def");
                break;
            case '4':
                strcpy(letters[i], "ghi");
                break;
            case '5':
                strcpy(letters[i], "jkl");
                break;
            case '6':
                strcpy(letters[i], "mno");
                break;
            case '7':
                strcpy(letters[i], "pqrs");
                break;
            case '8':
                strcpy(letters[i], "tuv");
                break;
            case '9':
                strcpy(letters[i], "wxyz");
                break;
        }
        
        total_combinations *= strlen(letters[i]);
    }
    
    // Print all letter sets
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("letters %d: %s\n", i, letters[i]);
    }
    
    // Declare array of sorted combinations (total_combinations rows, n+1 columns)
    // and an array keeping track of the current combination
    char combinations[total_combinations][n+1];
    int current_comb[n];
    
    // Initialize current_comb to zeros
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) current_comb[i] = 0;
    
    // Generate all combinations
    int k = 0;
    while (k < total_combinations){
        // Store current combination
        for (int set_idx = 0; set_idx < n; set_idx++){
            int letter_idx = current_comb[set_idx];
            combinations[k][set_idx] = letters[set_idx][letter_idx];
        }
        // Null-terminate the string
        combinations[k][n] = '\0';
        
        // Generate next combination
        // From the end of the combination indices
        for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
            // Increment index
            current_comb[i]++;
            // Set to zero if it exceeds the letters bounds, otherwise break out of the loop
            if (current_comb[i] == strlen(letters[i])){
                current_comb[i] = 0;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // Increment combinations count
        k++;
    }
    
    // Print all combinations
    for (int i=0; i<total_combinations; i++){
        printf("%s\n", combinations[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're my savior, thank you so much!